# Java lambda filter and map, can I avoid these repetitive calls?

Tags: java, lambda

I'm learning lambdas and I am wondering about the following code:

```
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    lines.add("#ignored");
    lines.add("   #ignored2");
    lines.add("Not Ignored");
    lines.add("also not ignored");
    lines.add("   also Not Ignored but lower CASE");

    lines.stream()
            .filter(line -> !line.trim().startsWith("#"))
            .map(line -> line.trim().toLowerCase())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

output:

```
not ignored
also not ignored
also not ignored but lower case
```

For both the filter and map lines, I'm calling trim() to strip any leading or tailing whitespace.

Is it possible here to trim the line once, store the result, and then use that result in the map?

Comment: _This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful._ That's your reason. Visit Meta if you want even more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `map` method at the beginning to trim the lines:

```
lines.stream()
        .map(String::trim) // Trim the spaces
        .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("#"))
        .map(String::toLowerCase)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: you can write `.map(String::trim)` :)

Comment: the same with toLowerCase

Comment: @maxpovver Thanx, I changed the answer to use method references.

Answer (score 2):

You could try below

```
lines.stream().map(String::trim).filter(line -> !line.startsWith("#")).map(String::toLowerCase).forEach(System.out::println);
```